# EF Core Transaction Changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor

is there a Property which indicates that there changes were made within a Transaction?

I use a Transaction inside a Razor-Component and when the user is a about to exit the Page I want to ask if he wants to apply or rollback his changes, but I only want to ask if there are changes were made.

Something like `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries` but in the context of IDbContextTransaction.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you wouldn't want to have this logic on the frontend (e.g. using dirty/touched input states, etc)? Putting this logic on the backend is unusual unless you need other clients to be aware of the pending changes.

Comment: well it's quite uncomfortable to adjust each element on an existing Page and I hope there is something similar to the DbContext.ChangeTracker within the Transaction.

Comment: Consider using a view service to back your edit form, and tracking state within the service.  Search "blazor edit state" for some resources.

Answer (score 0):

[Change detection and notification in Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/change-detection)

I would recommend looking into using the `dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` method.

Comment: after SaveChanges was called, the ChangeTracker doesn't track it anymore, that's why I am asking for IDbContextTransaction to know about those changes.